# can data binding object be null in android

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using databinding in my project. In a fragment I am using DataBinding like following

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment  {

     private FragmentExampleBinding mFragmentExampleBinding;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //initializing data binding object
        mFragmentExampleBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_example, container, false);
        // is there any posibility that mFragmentExampleBinding can be null
        View view = mFragmentExampleBinding.getRoot();
        return view;
      }
}
```

My question is, is there any possibility that databinding object may return null? Do we really need to do null check while using databinding ?

Comment: I keep getting null back in a feature module, that is a module where the `build.gradle` imports `com.android.feature` instead of `com.android.application`, I'm not sure why this is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it's quite trustworthy and I don't need to check it every time.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil#inflate

> ```
>  * @return The newly-created binding for the inflated layout or <code>null</code> if
>  * the layoutId wasn't for a binding layout.
> ```

But it may be null if there is something wrong in the xml.

However, if you decided to clear the view reference in the `onDestroyView`(set binding to null) to avoid memory leak, you do need to do null check or throw an exception in case you access binding after the view is destroyed.

At least for now, when using one activity + multiple fragments architectures, I have to set the binding(and other view references) to null to avoid the memory leak.